# Parse a JSON file with only root - Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, callback

I need to parse a JSON from The Movie Database structured as well:

```
    [
  {
    "iso_3166_1": "AD",
    "english_name": "Andorra"
  },
  {
    "iso_3166_1": "AE",
    "english_name": "United Arab Emirates"
  },
```

This my API service:

```
@GET("configuration/countries")
Call<LanguageModel> getLanguages(
        @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

I created this model to retrieve the data:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class LanguageModel implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("iso_3166_1")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("english_name")
    private String originalLanguage;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }
}
```

And then, I made this call to put all the pair of values into an HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, String> initializeMapLang() {
    HashMap<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<>();
    ApiService apiService = ApiBuilder.getClient(DetailActivity.this).create(ApiService.class);
    Call<LanguageModel> call = apiService.getLanguages(BuildConfig.API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LanguageModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LanguageModel> call, Response<LanguageModel> response) {
            Pair<String, String> resultLang =  new Pair<>(response.body().getId(), response.body().getOriginalLanguage());
            tmp.put(resultLang.first, resultLang.second);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LanguageModel> call, Throwable t) { }
    });
    return tmp;
}
```

The problem is that I do not get any response. Is my model correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api service is returning a flat list of `LanguageModel`. Retrofit can handle this for you, all you need to do is change the endpoint definition from

```
@GET("configuration/countries")
Call<LanguageModel> getLanguages(
        @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

to

```
@GET("configuration/countries")
Call<List<LanguageModel>> getLanguages(
        @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```